# Trying to target only Chrome on Windows using media queries

Tags: windows, css, google-chrome, media-queries

**Is it possible to target ONLY Chrome on Windows with media queries or other methods?**

I ask because I'm using the -webkit-text-stroke trick for smoothing Arial in Chrome/Windows, but I don't want the text-stroke to display in other Webkit browsers and Chrome/Mac OS. Not sure how to do this - the only thing I could think of was media queries or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

If not possible with CSS Media Queries, etc. you could try out some JavaScript.
One possible way could be to check `navigator.userAgent` in a way as shown in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/myTerminal/6963r/

And the above can easily be extended to limit on the basis on operating system too.

Comment: Thank you. I'll check that out soon when I can. :)